# Android: Why Sign in with Google button icon is not aligned properly?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-signin

I'm using Google [sign in button](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton) provided by the [com.google.android.gms.common](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton) library. However, the button icon is not aligned properly unlike it is shown in [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button). This is specially noticeable when using the dark color scheme.

**What I'm expecting**

[image: Expected result]

**What I'm getting**

[image: Current result]

**Code**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:colorScheme="dark"
    app:buttonSize="wide"/>
```

Before you say anything, yes it the same even with `app:buttonSize="standard"` and `app:colorScheme="light"`. Also changing the padding did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is an issue with the library it self. This may get fixed in a future update. For now only thing to do is to create a custom button according to the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button).

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is convenient to others to find this answer, thanks.